# Dagster Daemon sends heartbeats but starts no runs

Tags: dagster

I created a simplified project with dagster and started the dagster-daemon, however it starts no runs even though it sends heartbeats to the default sqlite daemon_heartbeats table.

I put all the files I needed in the same folder (at this point, they're just like hello world files), created a workspace.yaml and a dagster.yaml manually. Here is how the files look like:[image]
[image]

I also configured my repository like the following:
[image]

I believe, I did everything right, because I can load the repository from dagit without problems and I even see the option to turn the schedule on and off.
[image]

After doing all this, I started the dagster-daemon with `dagster-daemon run`. The logs are alright (in the sense that I don't get any errors):
[image]

And the daemon_heartbeats table does get updated regularly:
[image]

Nevertheless, when I check the daemon on dagit, I get the message that the daemon is not running.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the issue here? Am I overlooking somethin basic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but for anybody that can get in the same situation. Make sure you setup your DAGSTER_HOME variable to point to the dagster directory. For both dagit and dagster-daemon.

For example for Linux:

```
export DAGSTER_HOME=~/dagster
```

Windows:

```
set DAGSTER_HOME=c:\dagster
```